# slate.js based reactjs rich text editor reverse engineering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, materialize, slatejs

it all started from watching two slate.js demo videos in youtube

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K-qYdOPKT4
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMID1FbEZSk&t=3s

His name is Andrei Fiodorov and he showed in those demos how his rich text editor works using slate.js library. In the comment section he shared a snippet of code which is a glimpse of the overall code. I have started a sandbox pen here

https://codesandbox.io/s/rvp8j5q7n

looks like he used Materialize and npgrogress in his project. I a noob in React. I am interested about the beautiful UI Mr Andrei Fiodorov created successfully. But unfortunately couldn't render the page yet. I will be grateful if anybody could help me to render the UI.

Answer (score 3):

That sandbox specifies version 0.33.4 for Slate. However, in the [Changelog for 0.24.0](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/packages/slate/Changelog.md#0240--september-11-2017) the following is stated:

> The Html, Plain and Raw serializers are broken into new packages. Previously you'd import them from slate. But now you'll import them from slate-html-serializer and slate-plain-serializer. And the Raw serializer that was deprecated is now removed.
>
> The Editor and Placeholder components are broken into a new
>   React-specific package. Previously you'd import them from slate. But
>   now you import { Editor } from 'slate-react' instead.

Furthermore, you will need to uncomment the `React.renderDOM(...)` code and you'll need to configure Redux with a store and reducer before you can call the `connect(...)` code.

Comment: first of all thanks for answering. Will you please set up a working demo of the program in sandbox. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in react, but maybe component have to be mounted?

`render(<MyEditor />, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: At first I also thought that and added 
/*
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
*/
But I have found this error now "Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(MyEditor)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(MyEditor)".
looks like the problem is with redux now.

Comment: @coolsaint for me it give `Cannot read property 'deserialize' of undefined` in line 300 `let editorState = Raw.deserialize(initialState, { terse: true });`  have you changed something? by any chance the version of  `slate` in `package.json`

Comment: @evgeni fotia No I haven't changed anything in package.json

Comment: This error means that the `Raw` component is `undefined`. Maybe the video is outdated and this component isn't exist anymore or moved to another place.